# "Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration"

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees, func

When I have this,

```
public static object Create()
{
    return new object();
}
```

this works:

```
var m = typeof(Class).GetMethod("Create");
var e = Expression.Call(m);
Func<object> f = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(e).Compile();
```

But when I have this,

```
public static object Create(Type t)
{
    return new object();
}
```

this fails:

```
var m = typeof(Class).GetMethod("Create");
var e = Expression.Call(m, Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type)));
var t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo));
Func<object> f = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(e, t).Compile();
```

I get *An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll. Additional information: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration*. The parameter `t` is just expression for a dummy type `Foo`. I think that's irrelevant. Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: I think the title I given to this question is misleading. Can someone correct it?

Comment: @nawfal: You can do that yourself. Just edit your question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Of course I have the privilege, except that I am unsure of what the right one is. Was asking more knowledgable community to do that (so that it helps potential future visitors)

Comment: How about "Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration"?

Comment: @RichardHein went ahead

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you've said you want to use a parameter - but then you're not actually providing anywhere to specify it. You were creating two `ParameterExpression`s of different types, and then trying to convert the result into a `Func<object>` - which doesn't have any parameters at all. You want something like:

```
var m = typeof(Class).GetMethod("Create");
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type), "p");
var e = Expression.Call(m, p);
Func<Type, object> f = Expression.Lambda<Func<Type, object>>(e, p).Compile();
```

Note that the same `ParameterExpression` is used in the argument list for both the`Expression.Call` method and the `Expression.Lambda` methods.

Comment: I don't understand this - "Also note that I've explicitly created an array for the arguments to Expression.Call to avoid trying to use p as if it were the target of an instance method call."  It seems to work fine with just p, instead of an array ... can you expand on this a bit?

Comment: Also, using var e = Expression.Call(m, null, p) results in an "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: arg0".

Comment: @RichardHein: If you use `Expression.Call(m, p)` I'd expect that to be as if we were trying to call `p.Create()` effectively. Apparently not though... I'm not sure why, but I'll edit.

Comment: @RichardHein: Ah, got it. For instance methods the target of the call is the first argument, not the second. Doh.

Comment: @JonSkeet well written, accepted; somehow overlooked it. Can you tell me what is really the significance of `p` going into both `Expression.Call` and `Expression.Lambda`?

Comment: @nawfal: Yes - it's binding the two together. Imagine you were writing a lambda expression - you'd use `p => Create(p)` and the `p` refers to the same variable (the parameter) in both places. You might *expect* to be able to just create two `ParameterExpression` objects using the same name and bind that way, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, I understand, just new to this dynamic building thing :)

Comment: Ah yes, instance vs. statics ... good to highlight that.

Comment: Can't thank you enough, @JonSkeet!